# Setting up keras-rl2 on my M1 Macbook Pro

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am working on a project on Reinforcement Learning - and completely new at this. I installed keras-rl as
`pip install keras-rl`, however it caused an error as many has mentioned:

> `` TypeError: Keras symbolic inputs/outputs do not implement `__len__`. You may be trying to pass Keras symbolic inputs/outputs to a TF API that does not register dispatching, preventing Keras from automatically converting the API call to a lambda layer in the Functional Model. This error will also get raised if you try asserting a symbolic input/output directly. ``

And the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67738099/setting-up-deep-reinforcement-learning-environment-on-my-mac-m1-air) for this is to used keras-rl2. Howver I cannot install keras-rl2 on my Mac M1 as the output is following:

`ERROR: Cannot install keras-rl2==1.0.0, keras-rl2==1.0.1, keras-rl2==1.0.2, keras-rl2==1.0.3, keras-rl2==1.0.4 and keras-rl2==1.0.5 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.`

When I tried a specific version, i.e
`pip install keras-rl2==1.0.5`, the output is:

`ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from keras-rl2) (from versions: none)`

`ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow` 
I have tensorflow 2.6.0 installed by [Apple Developer guide](https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/). Any idea how I can install keras-rl2?

Comment: Ahhh no its just my university's ML course.

Answer (score 2):

**1. To install Tensorflow on M1 Macs**

https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/

**2. To Install Keras-rl2**

Open a terminal window and run these commands from:

https://github.com/keras-rl/keras-rl (last line changed)

```
git clone https://github.com/wau/keras-rl2.git
```

```
cd keras-rl
```

```
python3 setup.py install
```

The setup.py script will still tell you that it can't find a TensorFlow  version but you will still be able to import it using:

```py
import rl
```